# Microsoft Sharepoint Migration Tool (MSMT) site is not supported for Sharepoint 2010 designer workflow migration

Tags: migration, sharepointmigrationtool

We are trying to migrate Sharepoint 2010 designer workflows which is deployed in Sharepoint online site collection using Microsoft Sharepoint Migration Tool (MSMT). When we enter value in **URL of the workflow you want to migrate** as a SP online site collection url it thorws an error "**This site is not supported. Enter a site URL for Sharepoint 2010, 2013 and 2016**".

Can we migration 2010 designer workflow using this tool which is deployed in online site collection?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 workflows have been retired in SharePoint Online. They should have been removed from all tenants by now and do not work in SharePoint Online. More information can be found in this Microsoft support article:

[SharePoint 2010 workflow retirement](https://support.microsoft.com/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f)

**Edit:** SharePoint 2010 workflows cannot be converted to SharePoint 2013 or Power Automate flows using the SharePoint Migration Tool.

Comment: Yes because of that we want to convert Sharepoint 2010 workflows to Power automate OR Sharepoint 2013 workflows. So is it possible using Microsoft Sharepoint Migration Tool in sharepoint online site collection

Comment: I have updated my answer, following your comment. Please upvote or mark as the answer, if the response is helpful.